# How to remove word from string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to remove a specific word from string in shell script.

My text file contains below data

```
***** Failed tests *****
Devices                  Class                Test
Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10   Addition             productCalculation
```

I want to remove `Devices` and `Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10`

`Nexus_5_29_2(AVD) - 10`  is not constant it may change to `Nexus_5_29_1(AVD) - 10`  or `Nexus_5_29(AVD) - 10`

Expected output is

```
***** Failed tests *****
Class                Test
Addition             productCalculation
```

how can i achive this ? `awk` is preferable

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: @ProBot : So, you want to remove the first n characters from each line?

Comment: @Cyrus i am new to shell script. i paresed that data from html document using html2text . any how i am stucked with this. i tried with awk to remove the device name. but  failed to remove (AVD) - 10

Comment: @user1934428 expected output is mentioned in question. cant spcifies the number because that data is comming from html report

Comment: Consider going back to the original HTML and using an HTML parser to generate the final output you want instead of this intermediate format.

Comment: @ProBot : How can you then **visusally** know how large the columns are? If all of them are alligned as in the header. you could calculate the column with from the header.

Answer (score 0):

Use **sed** for replace or search and delete

```
sed -i -e 's/Devices//g' filename.txt
```

Awk solution:

```
cat filename.txt | awk '{print  $2 $3 }'
```

To do as you want, I need more information.

Comment: awk will not work, unless the field separator is tab not space and if you specify it as such. Comma is missing.  Also UUOC.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^Devices/{N;s/^\S+\s+(.*\n)Nexus_5_29(_[0-9]+)?\(AVD\) - 10\s+/\1/};P;D' file
```

If a line begins `Devices` append the next line and remove the first column and its associated whitespace of the those two lines if the second line matches the required string.

N.B. The appended line may not match the criteria for the second line, in which case the first line should be printed as normal and the process repeated with the second line taking its place, hence the reason for `P` and `D` commands. All other lines will be printed as normal.

From the criteria you described, the above solution may well be suffice. If, however a more generic solution is needed, perhaps?:

```
sed -E '/^Devices/{N;s/^\S+\s+(.*\n)\w+_[0-9]+_[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)?\([A-Z]{3}\) - [0-9]+\s+/\1/};P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your file has only spaces and no tabs, you can delete the first n characters for the rows except the header.

```
> awk 'NR>1 {$0=substr($0,26)} 1' file
***** Failed tests *****
Class                Test
Addition             productCalculation
```

Answer (score 0):

find the position of the second header in second line and trim left side.

```
$ awk 'NR==2{n=match($0,/ [^ ]/)} {print substr($0,n+1)}' file

***** Failed tests *****
Class                Test
Addition             productCalculation
```

Assumes headers are one word each (without spaces).